# How to compile Blender from source?

Tags: build, cygwin, makefile, blender

I just downloaded [blender souce](http://download.blender.org/source/blender-2.49b.tar.gz).

***How do I build it?***

I tried `make` command, but I am getting this:

[image]

Btw, I am doing this on Windows using Cygwin.

Comment: Note, the hand written makefiles referenced in this post have been removed from Blender, now Blender uses CMake. Cygwin support has been removed for some time now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Large and complicated projects such as Blender often have many dependencies and intricacies which makes building them yourself a pretty daunting task. Usually the source code is accompanied by the build instructions which tell you how to build it. [But you often can find them on the web, too.](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender)

Comment: your original answer was okay too :)

Comment: from the link you have provided, Windows compilation is too difficult. If I try it on my Redhat machine, what would it qualify as among `Ubuntu Gutsy, Hardy, Jaunty`, `Arch Linux` and `Gentoo`? I am referring to the distributions provided here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/2.4x/Linux

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should probably start at http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender

Cygwin is messy but possible. On Windows I would strongly recommend building under VisualStudio. Have a look at

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Hackers_Guide/Building/Cygwin_Make

if you want to build in cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your sdl-config is setup to the environment variables.

if not, then set up to the directory where sdl-config exists (`setenv` command)

if SDL-config doesn't exist, try and install it (I know Ubuntu `sudo aptitude install libsdl1.2-dev`).

 Once installed, then check if the path has been included to environment variable (`env` command)

If there are any distros missing, download them here (for linux, http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/2.4x/Linux)